# Cordova: I can't get the location of fakeGPS in cordova 3.1 using android

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, ibm-mobilefirst

In the previous version of the project that I'm working we were using worklight 5.0.6 (cordova 2.3) and we were able to get the gps position using fakeGPS (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps&hl=pt_BR), but now we are using worklight 6.1 (cordova 3.1) and the gps position returned to us using fakeGPS is null.

I tried to get the source code of cordova in this link (http://archive.apache.org/dist/cordova/) but seems that some files are missing. In the plugins part I don't know exactly what was the version of the geolocation plugin used in the 3.1 and 2.3 version.

Someone know what are happening or could send to me the source code of the cordova 3.1 and 2.3 to compare the difference between these versions?

Comment: Does your manifest contain the GPS permission?

Comment: Yes, I include all is possible for gps location: ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS, ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION and LOCATION_HARDWARE to guarantee that is not a permission case.

Comment: Someone knows a place where can I consult all plugin versions of cordova? For example, cordova 3.4.1 uses camera-plugin 0.2.7.

Comment: Hi Fabio, you can get the cordova version--> plugin version mapping from the Cordova blog: http://cordova.apache.org/ Starting in version...3.2 I think. For example, here are the plugin versions in Cordova 3.4: http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/02/20/cordova-340.html  For 3.1 I think you need to do some detective work.

Comment: Have you enabled mock locations on your device?

Comment: Yes. I have enabled it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the Mobile Browser Simulator; the [geolocation widget](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/cmbsgeoworkwl.html?resultof=%22%67%70%73%22%20%22%67%70%22%20) there and the [scenario editor](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_overview_testlocservices_geo_wifi.html) can be used to simulate fake GPS locations for hybrid applications.

Comment: I stop to work on this problem for these days (because there are others features under my responsibility) but we need use fake gps on the final app, on device. Thanks.

Comment: I think then that your best approach would be to use Mock Location from another application - see https://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html 
Note that you can see the location "jumping" around if it's still also able to get the location from GPS / Wifi. My recommendation here would be to turn off WiFi and use GPS from a location where you can't actually pick up any GPS signal.